# How to get the data value during Jquery Ajax calling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I'm calling Ajax like below

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        url: path,
        dataType: "json",

        data: '{  "jsondata":' + jsondata + ',"key":"' + getValue('id') + '"}',
        success: function (data) {
            callback(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            callback(error.responseText);

        }
    });
```

I want to get the "Data" value at calling time because after the call the execution doesn't goes to the desired web method and the error is showing like 
`""Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027obj\u0027..."`
I have to track the the Ajax posting value during Ajax call and find out what is the problem with posting data.Is there any tricks to get the data value before Ajax calling?
Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit:** I'm sending the jsondata value like below

```
var jsondata = '{ "pagenumber":"' + pagenumber + '","sortColumn":"' + sortColumn + '","sortDirection":"' + sortDirection + '","rowPerPage":"' + rowPerPage + '"}';
```

Thanks.

Comment: you need to check your `getValue('id')` it should be `getValue(id)`

Comment: Have you tried with before send event??

Comment: I must have misunderstood the question, because the answer to me looks like `var data = '{ ... }'; console.log(data); $.ajax({... data: data, ...});`. Can you explain a behavior you need a bit more?

Comment: @gopal Please check url and  data: '{  "jsondata":' + jsondata + ',"key":"' + getValue('id') + '"}',

Comment: is jsondata already JSON.stringified otherwise try JSON.stringify(jsondata)

Comment: The getValue('id') returning a string value correctly @Webruster

Comment: @GopalBiswas can you paste that method

Comment: Please see the edit section of my question.

Comment: @GopalBiswas i observed two points 1. MethodName is different  `getValue` in ajax and `getQueryStringValue` in your comment 2. InJavascript you don't need to send id in single quotation just pass the value

Comment: @GopalBiswas another point to be noted a trival one : *parameters must match between client- and server-side with case-sensitivity.*

Comment: The method name is "getValue" and the definition like @Webruster getValue= function (key) { return unescape(window.location.search.replace(new RegExp("^(?:.*[&\\?]" + escape(key).replace(/[\.\+*]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\=([^&]*))?)?.*$", "i"), "$1")); }

Comment: I am sending request data value like  {  "jsondata":{ "pagenumber":"0","sortColumn":"Name","sortDirection":"asc","rowPerPage":"10"},"key":"PPCrAV0oUGhy1cRdNEiN/ohdzAwD3+Qyyn5ozvhZ1B6STo0KrY+/Vggfnc4v12JS"
}     Where is the problem in this requested data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just checking with below code - 
please have a look. please check beforesend content

```
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

    url: '/dummy',
    dataType: "json",

    data: '{dummy:"dummy"}',
    success: function (data) {
       alert(data);
    },
    error: function (error) {
       alert(error);

    },
      beforeSend: function(data,data1) {

    console.log('before'+data1.data)
 },
});
 })
});
```

Comment: The data value is sending like {  "jsondata":{ "pagenumber":"0","sortColumn":"Name","sortDirection":"asc","rowPerPage":"10"},"key":"PPCrAV0oUGhy1cRdNEiN/ohdzAwD3+Qyyn5ozvhZ1B6STo0KrY+/Vggfnc4v12JS"
}

Answer (score 0):

```
   var path = "test_ajax.php";
   var jsondata = "Testing123";
   var test = "test";

    var data = {jsondata : jsondata,key : test};


    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

    url: path,
    dataType: "json",

    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
       alert("success:"+data);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert("failure"+error.responseText);

    }
});
```